# Ant: Not finding my @ContextConfiguration

Tags: spring-mvc, ant, junit4

We have a Spring 3 MVC application and JUnit test cases for spring controllers. The Junit version is 4.8.1 which supports ContextConfiguration annotation.

Here is how I am adding context configuration in my test stub

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/myappconfig.xml")
```

I am able to run the junits locally, but when I am trying to run this with my ant build script, it throws an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

I tried to set classpath element to the WebContent, then upto web-inf, nothing works out.

Comment: My guess is it's a path issue.  When you run locally your base path is probably different than when you run with ant so it finds file:WebContent/... but when you run with ant it doesn't find that file.  Is there more in the error message that says where it is trying to load the ApplicationContext from when you run from ant?

Comment: @digitaljoel Here is the error: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [file:WebContent/WEB-INF/myappconfig.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: WebContent\WEB-INF\myappconfig.xml (The system cannot find the path specified.)

Comment: @digitaljoel Here is how I am trying to add classpath to junit: <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" fork="yes" maxmemory="512m"> <classpath> <path location="${source}/ABCWeb"/>

Comment: I suspect you're going to have to modify your contextconfiguration location.  Find out what the base directory is when you are running your tests, and then find out what it is when you run with ant and figure out how to get your location pointed appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

i'm using

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath*:application-test.xml" })
```

and my application-test.xml resides under main/resources